# how to define amazon-cloudwatch boto3.client in python user-defined-functions

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I'm working on a Python 3 script designed to get S3 space utilization statistics from AWS CloudFront using the Boto3 library.

I started with the AWS CLI and found I could get what I'm after with a command like this:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name BucketSizeBytes --namespace AWS/S3 --start-time 2017-03-06T00:00:00Z --end-time 2017-03-07T00:00:00Z --statistics Average --unit Bytes --r


from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import boto3

seconds_in_one_day = 86400  # used for granularity

cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

response = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace='AWS/S3',
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'BucketName',
            'Value': 'foo-bar'
        },
        {
            'Name': 'StorageType',
            'Value': 'StandardStorage'
        }
    ],
    MetricName='BucketSizeBytes',
    StartTime=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7),
    EndTime=datetime.now(),
    Period=seconds_in_one_day,
    Statistics=[
        'Average'
    ],
    Unit='Bytes'
)

print(response)
```

If I execute above code it is returning json output ,but I want to define function from cloudwatch on wards entire code ..and make it parameterized,but the problem is when i define a function

It returns. Error code saying that response variable not defined...

Pls suggest how to use that in function

Comment: Can you add the full code for the function you wrote and the way you're trying to use it?

Comment: This is the function i have defined
def cpu_util(DBI,m_name,stat):
     seconds_in_day = 86400  # used for granularity
 cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
 response = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
        Namespace='AWS/RDS',
        Dimensions=[ {
            'Name': 'CPU',
            'Value': DBI }],
       MetricName=m_name
       StartTime=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1),
       EndTime=datetime.now(),
       Period=30*seconds_in_day,
       Statistics=stat
 )
DBI = 'CPUUtilization'
cpu_util(DBI,m_name,stat)
its says response field not defined

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code so the formatting is visible? Also, make sure to add the full code. I see here comma is missing after `m_name`, `m_name` and `stat` are not defined, imports are missing ...